# how to select from a table in access with a string variable

Tags: c#, oledbdataadapter

I have a `database` in ms-access and wanted to select from it,

I know my question is very simple but I couldn't find the solution for it

this is how I want to select:

```
public static void SearchRationCreatorName(string RationCreator)
    {
        string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager....
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
        OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter
("Select * from tRations where tRations.RationCreator= [RationCreator]", Connection);

        DataTable Dtable = new DataTable();
        DataA.Fill(Dtable);
```

but instead of selecting one row it select all of records in that table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That didn't show up well in the comment. 
I think you mean

```
"Select * from tRations where RationCreator= '"+RationCreator+"'"
```

The way you worded your title suggests you may want to use a string in place of a tablename but your code suggests otherwise. IF you wanted to know how to select from a dynamic table, let me know.

Also, this will select all rows that match rationcreator. If you only want one row, use:

```
"Select TOP 1 * from tRations where RationCreator= '"+RationCreator+"'"
```

with or without an ORDER BY predicate

Comment: In Access, you use a single quote to show text, and the # sign to show date. So a number is WHERE myNum = 6. Text is WHERE fName = 'Bill' and date is WHERE myBirthday=#04/08/2000#

Comment: that was all I need now and in the future, tanks for your very complete answer, it helped a lot

Comment: Glad to help... take care!